# loop user input for years entered?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get to grips with some c# exercises as a beginner to programming. I currently looking at a rainfall program that has to  grt the user to input the rainfall over the  a number of years and calculate the total and average rainfall per year. How do i get the loop to run for the number of years that the user has input, i have tried this and the loop is infinite
 int Numyears = 0;

```
        int Rainfall = 0;
        double avrRainfall = 0.0;

        string[] Month = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };



        Console.WriteLine("please enter number of years");
        Numyears = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        while(Numyears <= 1)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Minimum number of years is 1 Please re-enter");
            Numyears = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }
       for (int y = 0; y <= Numyears;)


        for(int i = 0; i < Month.Length; i ++)

        { 
            Console.WriteLine(" Enter inches of rainfall for {0}", Month[i]);


            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        for (int i = 0;i < Month.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" {1} Total", i + 1, Month[i]);
        }







        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You are never incrementing `y`, did you mean `for (int y = 0; y <= Numyears; y++)`?

Comment: Yes to start the  outter loop for the year i put that  in but it seems to loop forever..Head is completely melted with now

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Numyears; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Loop {0} of {1}", i, Numyears));
}
```

Comment: I tried to put this in but the message.show comes up as an error

Comment: Write a program that uses nested loops to collect data and calculate the average rainfall over a period of years. First the program should ask for the number of years. The outer loop will iterate once for each year. The inner loop will iterate 12 times, once for each month.  Each iteration of the inner loop will ask the user for the inches of rainfall for that month. After all iterations, the program should display the number of months, the total inches of rainfall, and the average rainfall per month for the entire period. Use Methods to solve the problem.

Comment: i cant get my head around the nested loops,Once the inner loop runs through the array(months) and the user enters the rainfall amount, if the chose say 2 years,how do i get the 2nd year to cycle after year one